# CSV file with commas in the address

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I have to copy a `.csv` file in a table using postgresql. 
I'll have three attributes: `name, address, postcode`.

I'm usign the command:

```
COPY schemaname.tablename FROM '/tmp/tablename.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

The problem is that in some rows there are commas in the address' text and so the database considers them as delimiters (eg. `John,"22, King's road", 89224!`

The address is also quoted (`" "`) and there's no header.

Can anyone please suggest some solution?

Comment: I think the best course of action would be to 'clean' your csv file. So, remove all commas that are not used to seperate the values and remove all double quotes.

Comment: I _think_ this should work: `copy ... with (format csv, delimiter ',', quote '"', header false)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's working! thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a text-qualifier, you should tell postgresql to make use of that in differentiating between commas that are embedded in a string and commas that delimit fields:

```
COPY schemaname.tablename
FROM '/tmp/tablename.csv'
DELIMITER ','
QUOTE '"';
```

Full list of options for `COPY`: [PostgreSQL - SQL Copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSV format instead of a delimiter

```
COPY schemaname.tablename
FROM '/tmp/tablename.csv' CSV
```